# Get data from multiple input file and write to another 1 file

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a list of *.mto file containing my simulation result. They have the format as:

```
 vtpr             vtpf             temper           alter#            
  5.849e-01        3.034e-01        2.500e+01       1
```

I want to get the value of vtpr and vtpf in each input files, then save them to a result file. Somebody suggest me use sed but i have no idea how can it works with multiple files. 
I use this code to print the 2nd line but in the result file, there's only the value of the final input files, not all the value because it's overwrited each time. can u give me some suggest ?
thanks for help.

`find . -name '*.mt0' -exec sed -n '2w result.txt' "{}`"\;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) with correct delimiter(default is TAB)

```
find . -name '*.mt0' -type f -exec sed -n '2{p;q}' {} \; | cut -f2 -d' ' > output
```

Comment: Thanks u very much, it worked ! anw, Can you tell me the meaning of '2{p,q}' in 'sed' command ?

Comment: @kerry_13, find 2 line, print it and quit the file

Answer (score 0):

awk can do it all

```
awk 'FNR==2 {print $1, $2}' *.mt0 >output
```